# How to display the image which is not in current directory

Tags: jquery, html, json

I am using jquery to display results get by json object, here for image tag i used a hardcoded value.

```
$.getJSON("http://192.168.1.9:8983/solr/db/select/?wt=json&&start=0&rows=100&q=" + q + "&json.wrf=?", function(result) {
    $.each(result.response.docs, function(i, item) {
        html += "<br>UID_PK: =" + item.UID_PK;
        html += "<br>Name: =" + item.name;
        var src1 = "ABW0149_reg.jpg";
        html += "<img src=" + src1 + " />";
    });

    $("#result").html(html);
});
```

where "result" is a `<div>`

my problem is when i put `ABW0149_reg.jpg` in the same directory in which my this html file is it display the image but when i want to use image from some other path i do like this 
`file:///E:/ABW0149_reg.jpg` but it does not display the image. Why is so, tell me how can i use image from some other source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue here is that all modern browsers prohibit displaying local (`file:///`) images embedded in non-local (`http://`) pages.

It should work if you use some other remote path (like `192.168.1.10/images/image.jpg`).

Comment: than how can i achieve this if i want to use image from the same system but just from the different directory.

Comment: @Romi you mean, an image from the local system? You probably can't - you'd have to make it available through `http://` somehow

Comment: @Pekka:how can i make it available through http.See i have a running server at port localhost:8986, where shuld i put the images in this server so that i can use it on port localhost:8080

Comment: @Romi you'd have to install a new server, or configure your existing one to serve stuff on that port

Comment: C i have two running server one at tomcat port 8080, and one jetti at port 8986..as in my question i used a getJson to get json object from 8986..which is actually a json formated file, n i am getting my required data through parsing. now similarly i want to display image which is on 8086(jetti) whose url  i am getting by json bt unalbe to display it, please suggest me how can i do it.

Comment: I suspect if you're making an Ajax call to a resource on a different port, the request is probably not working out at all because of the Single Origin Policy?

Answer (score 0):

`<img src="file:///..." />` actually tries to load image from client's hard drive.

Comment: then what should i do if i want to use image from some other directory

Comment: @Romi Make this image accessible via `http` somehow.

Comment: how can i make it available through http.See i have a running server at port localhost:8986, where shuld i put the images in this server so that i can use it on port localhost:8080

Answer (score 0):

Your images need to be within the same public-html/wwwroot.

You can then use relative addressing (eg ../image.jpg) or absolute(/folder/image.jpg).